# What are historical applications of geometry to measuring distances beyond human reach?

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

I am searching for books and articles about applications of Geometry, in particular to the problem of computing distances and lengths which are apparently beyond human reach. As an example, consider the computations of the size of the Earth by Eratosthenes and by Al-Biruni. I am particularly interested in those cases in which (as in the examples that I mentioned) it is known that those methods were actually used in practice.

Comment: Robert Hahn, The Metaphysics of the Pythagorean Theorem. Thales, Pythagoras, Engineering, Diagrams... (NY: 2018), a book with some examples (height of pyramids, distance at sea, tunnels).

Comment: There is a very nice book: M. Berger, Geometry, which describes a lot of applications.

Comment: You may want to look at Tao's slides on the cosmic distance ladder.

Comment: Rather recently,  see "The Great Escape," in which POWs used triangulation survey techniques to determine necessary tunnel length.  Sadly, they lacked accurate levels; the tunnels sloped slightly up, and became the hypotenuse rather than the leg (hence short of desired destination)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the down to Earth geometry see [Surveying Instruments of Greece and Rome by Lewis](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Izau5_ihmsC&source=gbs_navlinks_s). For the astronomical measurements, which aside from the names mentioned would include Aristarchus, Ptolemy, see [Measuring the Universe: Cosmic Dimensions from Aristarchus to Halley by van Helden](https://books.google.com/books?id=L-yb7GX9mQIC&dq=Aristarchus+Eratosthenes+al-Biruni+geometry+measuring+distances&source=gbs_navlinks_s). [The Mathematics of the Heavens and the Earth by van Brummelen](https://books.google.com/books?id=bHD8IBaYN-oC&dq=Aristarchus+Eratosthenes+al-Biruni+geometry+measuring+distances&source=gbs_navlinks_s) focuses specifically on applications of trigonometry. The [History of Stellar Measurement website](https://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~mjp/history_parallax.html) lists some more recent applications to the parallax measurements.